# syntax of awk to parse next line of file

Tags: awk

What is the correct syntax to have the `awk` parse the next line as well?  The next in bold is where I think it should go, but I wanted to ask the experts since I am a beginner.  Thank you.

```
awk 'NR==2 {split($2,a,"[_.>]");b=substr(a[4],1,length(a[4]-1));print a[2]+0,b,b,substr(a[4],length(a[4])),a[5]}' **{nextline=NR+1;next}** OFS="\t" out_position.txt > out_parse.txt
```

For example, if there are 2 entries in a file the first gets parsed by the code but not the second.

Content:

```
Input Variant   Errors  Chromosomal Variant Coding Variant(s)
NM_004004.5:c.79G>A     NC_000013.10:g.20763642C>T  NM_004004.5:c.79G>A XM_005266354.1:c.79G>A  XM_005266355.1:c.79G>A  XM_005266356.1:c.79G>A
NM_004004.5:c.283G>C        NC_000013.10:g.20763438C>G  NM_004004.5:c.283G>C    XM_005266354.1:c.283G>C XM_005266355.1:c.283G>C XM_005266356.1:c.283G>C
```

Comment: Awk automatically processes every line in a file unless you tell it not to. Change your `NR==2` to `NR>=2`. As it is now, it only process Record 2 because of that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to process all lines but the header, here you are: (newlines are only here for readability, you can remove them if needed)

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR>1 {
       split($2,a,"[_.>]");
       b=substr(a[4],1,length(a[4]-1));
       print a[2]+0,b,b,substr(a[4],length(a[4])),a[5]
     }'  out_position.txt > out_parse.txt
```